# WPF Treeview HierarchicalDataTemplate Drag and drop

Tags: wpf, treeview, drag, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a treeview in wpf that is built using the xaml below. It is a well structured data source, and I am having a lot of trouble dragging and dropping. I have tried several methods, all to no avail. Can anyone tell me what the standard procedure is for doing this type of thing?

```
<TreeView x:Name="_treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logic:Statement}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PagedChildren}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatementName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logic:StatementPage}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Page: "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageIndex}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logic:StatementFund}">
                    <Border  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="25">
                        <WrapPanel Margin="30 0 30 0" Width="150" Height="150" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Fund"/>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fund: "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FundNumber}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Logic:StatementPreviousCycle}">
                    <Border  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="25">
                        <WrapPanel Margin="30 0 30 0" Width="150" Height="150" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Previous Cycle"/>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fund: "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FundNumber}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                                <WrapPanel Margin="10 0 0 0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>

            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i use the techniques on this [site](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) for a general drag and drop.

tree view can get messy, if you want to know which node you are **preivewMouseDown**'ing on, to then use as your drag item you can end up walking the visual tree. there is some code to do that [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent). another way is to subclass treeview, and treeviewitem, then you can override the preview mouse down on each tree view item, and tell your derived parent treeview about it, which could set the tree view item to be the selected item.

Comment: The problem comes in to the TreeView itself, how do I get the selectedNode on mousebutton down (before the node is selected). Also, the binding gets screwed up using the normal ways it seems.

Comment: The website you listed at wpftutorial.net really saved me. =)